# combine multiple regex to extract sub string from : separated string

Tags: java, regex

I have been stuck for some time developing a single regex to extract a path from either of the following strings :

```
1.  "life:living:fast"
2.  "life"
3.  ":life"
4.  ":life:"
```

I have these regex expressions to use :

```
(.{3,}):", ":(.{3,}):", ":(.{3,})", "(.{3,})
```

The first match is all I need. i.e. the desired result for each should be the string located where the word life is.  consider life to be a variable

But for some reason combining these individual regex's is a pain: If I excecute them sequentially I get the word 'life' extracted. However I am unable to combine them into one.

I appreciate your effort.

Comment: Not very clear what you're asking... can you post some desired input vs output?

Comment: @Mena please see my edit,  the desired result for each should be the string located where the word life is.

Comment: Still unclear. So you want to find whether `"life"` is contained within your `String`s? Or you want the index of `"life"`? Or...?

Comment: @Mena consider life to be a place holder or a variable, i.e the string could be *1:*2:*3 or *1 or :*1 or :*1: where *1 is a string that does not contain :

Comment: Yes but it's still unclear what you want to do with it. Posting some input vs output might help a great deal here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the first `life` with the colons, you can use this:

```
^:?(?:.{3,}?)(?::|$)
```

[See demo](http://regex101.com/r/eS5mZ0)

If you prefer the first `life` without the colons, switch to this:

```
((?<=^:)|^)([^:]{3,}?)(?=:|$)
```

[See demo](http://regex101.com/r/jZ2aY8)

**How it Works #1: `^:?(?:.{3,}?)(?::|$)`**

- With `^:?`, at the beginning of the string, we match an optional colon
- `(?:.{3,}?)` lazily matches three or more chars up to...
- `(?::|$)` a colon or the end of the string

**How it Works #1: `((?<=^:)|^)([^:]{3,}?)(?=:|$)`**

- `((?<=^:)|^)` ensures that we are either positioned at the beginning of the string, or after a colon immediately after the beginning of the string
- `([^:]{3,}?)` lazily matches chars that are not colons...
- up to a point where the lookahead `(?=:|$)` can assert that what follows is a colon or the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern, since you are looking for the first word:

```
(?<=^:?)[^:]{3,}
```

Note that this pattern doesn't check all the string.

Comment: It works too and is precise. but I will stick to zx81's answer as it is broken down to my simple understanding.